# Using the Git folder as my main folder, or as a copy of the actual work folder?

Tags: git

At the moment I'm using two folders on my PC - a Projects folder and a Git folder.

I work on the code in the files in Projects folder, copy it all to the Git folder when it's ready for committing and commit and sync.

Should I just be working on the code in the Git folder and cutting out the copy and paste?

I work on two different machines - my PC desktop and my Mac Air when I'm away. Recently, and for the first time, I did this copy and paste and accidentally copied over the later version of the code in the Git folder on my PC; I had done some work on the Mac the day before.

What's the accepted best practice?

Comment: If you copy/paste you lose all the nice features of Git such as diff, merge, conflicts. For copy/paste you don't need a SCM (but you should definitely use one!)

Comment: "Should I just be working on the code in the Git folder and cutting out the copy and paste?" The answer to that question is yes. However, it will help us help you if we know what you expected to gain from copying the files. Someone could then explain in what way Git provides the same functionality...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't copy !

There's no point in doing it and it's prone to accident as you noticed.

Simply do your git operations in your work repository, and use `push`/`fetch` operations to propagate to other repositories.